# Twilio Outbound Calling

Tags: api, twilio

I'm trying to create a call centre web application where the server on-behalf of the sales team makes outbound calls; when answered a greeting is played asking the person a two/three (at most) questions; based on the answers the outbound call will be transferred to a call queue that will be serviced/answered by one of the sales staff for that queue.

What should I be considering with regards to Twilio; is this possible? can you tell how many sales staff are connected to a queue that aren't on calls ?

etc..

I'm a noob to this sort of thing so sorry if this is a simple task that is available somewhere online.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Hey Grahame, whilst all of this is possible with Twilio, this sounds like a more in depth and opinion based question than stackoverflow should deal with. It's probably best to talk to our sales team. Fill in the form here https://www.twilio.com/help/sales and someone will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

For those looking to jump right in to making outgoing calls, give this a try:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/rest/call-request

The example in Python (beginner friendly):

```
# Download the library from twilio.com/docs/libraries
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Get these credentials from http://twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

# Make the call
call = client.calls.create(to="+14085551234",  # Any phone number
                           from_="+12125551234", # Must be a valid Twilio number
                           url="http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.ambient")
print call.sid
```